# Google Analytics getTotalsForAllResults inconsistent for different dimensions

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

```
print_r($service->data_ga->get('ga:78834361', '2014-01-01', 'today', 'ga:visitors')->getTotalsForAllResults());
print_r($service->data_ga->get('ga:78834361', '2014-01-01', 'today', 'ga:visitors', array('dimensions' => 'ga:visitorType'))->getTotalsForAllResults());
print_r($service->data_ga->get('ga:78834361', '2014-01-01', 'today', 'ga:visitors', array('dimensions' => 'ga:operatingSystem'))->getTotalsForAllResults());
print_r($service->data_ga->get('ga:78834361', '2014-01-01', 'today', 'ga:visitors', array('dimensions' => 'ga:browser'))->getTotalsForAllResults());
print_r($service->data_ga->get('ga:78834361', '2014-01-01', 'today', 'ga:visitors', array('dimensions' => 'ga:networkLocation'))->getTotalsForAllResults());
print_r($service->data_ga->get('ga:78834361', '2014-01-01', 'today', 'ga:visitors', array('dimensions' => 'ga:city'))->getTotalsForAllResults());
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [ga:visitors] => 120
)
Array
(
    [ga:visitors] => 123
)
Array
(
    [ga:visitors] => 121
)
Array
(
    [ga:visitors] => 121
)
Array
(
    [ga:visitors] => 128
)
Array
(
    [ga:visitors] => 131
)
```

Why are the results inconsistent? Everything is the same except for the dimensions.

As requested, I have tried with "ga:visits" instead of ga:visitors. The results are consistent here. Even more confusion.

```
Array
(
    [ga:visits] => 184
)
Array
(
    [ga:visits] => 184
)
Array
(
    [ga:visits] => 184
)
Array
(
    [ga:visits] => 184
)
Array
(
    [ga:visits] => 184
)
Array
(
    [ga:visits] => 184
)
```

After some thought, is it because during that time frame, a new visitor may have revisited the site again at a later date still within the time frame, thus flagging them as a returning visitor? (for second line of code. Similar logic for the other lines?)

Comment: please put <pre> tag then use print_r instead of vardump and show me

Comment: I have done so, but what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Have you tried ga:visits instead of ga:visitors?

Comment: I have edited my post using ga:visits.

Comment: Can you check if the data is sampled?

Comment: @PetrHavlík if you look at the low numbers comming back i dont think the data is sampled.

Comment: @DaImTo true true... can you list the dimensions in the output just to see what numbers "are missing"?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the diffrent reports on the GA website you will notice that they use, Visits,Visitors,Pageviews, and unique Pageviews.  They are all tracked diffrently, depending on what you are trying to show its best to know the diffrence between them.

---

**Visits vs. Visitors**

Analytics measures both visits and  visitors in your account. Visits represent the number of individual `sessions` initiated by all the `visitors` to your site. If a user is inactive on your site for 30 minutes or more, any future activity is attributed to a `new session`. Users that leave your site and return within 30 minutes are counted as part of the `original session`.

The initial session by a user during any given date range is considered to be an `additional visit` and `an additional visitor`. Any future sessions from the same user during the selected time period are counted as additional `visits`, but **not** as additional `visitors`.

**Pageviews vs. Unique Pageviews**

A pageview is defined as a `view of a page` on your site that is being tracked by the Analytics tracking code. If a visitor clicks `reload` after reaching the page, this is counted as an `additional pageview`. If a user `navigates` to a different page and then `returns to the original` page, a `second pageview` is recorded as well.

A unique pageview, as seen in the Content Overview report, aggregates pageviews that are generated by the `same user during the same session`. A unique pageview represents the number of sessions during which that page was viewed one or more times.

Comment: That is all true, but doesn't explain why the total number of unique visitors differ if sliced by different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

**No_name**,

one more hint -- use different end-date (ideally today - 2 days).

**The data might not have been processed yet (Google claims in some cases, it might take up to [48 hours to process everything](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)).**

I have just tested something similar and I got the correct number for both visits/visitors no matter what dimension I picked.

Hope this helps.